# Си проблема с разыменованием

Tags: c, указатели, память

Пишу реализацию списка. Сказали - переделать в двунаправленный.

```
void pushToStart(struct TreeStruct **start, char data) {
    struct TreeStruct *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct TreeStruct));
    
    //(*start)->prev = tmp;
    
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = (*start);
    tmp->prev = NULL;
    (*start) = tmp;
}
```

Закоментированная строка - то, что по моему мнению необходимо для реализации. Однако если строку раскомментить, вылезет segmentation error, если же попробовать (**start).prev = tmp; , то будет такая же ошибка. Во всех остальных случаях ошибка несоответстия типов

*В качестве start передается struct TreeStruct* tree; pushToStart(&tree, NULL)*

Как быть?

Comment: Так Вы свой `struct TreeStruct* tree;` инициализируйте чем-то.

Comment: Надо понимать, что `start` это адрес дескриптора списка, который  имеет ту же структуру, что и все узлы? Тогда логично предположить, что `(*start)->next` указатель на первый, а `(*start)->prev` на последний элемент списка (обычно дескриптор двунаправленного списка конструируют так). Если вы хотите добавить новый первый элемент в такую конструкцию, то должно получится как-то так: `tmp->prev = 0; if (tmp->next = (*start)->next) tmp->next->prev = tmp; (*start)->next = tmp; if ((*start)->prev == 0) (*start)->prev = tmp;` Это при условии, что изначально дескриптор инициализирован нулями

Comment: @EOF конечно, через malloc

Comment: Посмотрите на простой пример реализации двунаправленного списка: https://pastebin.com/TwN3SiCd, а то понапишите всякого, потом чёрт ногу сломит...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю,

```
struct TreeStruct* tree; 
pushToStart(&tree, NULL);
```

Итак, что мы имеем? Имеем

```
(*start)->prev = tmp;
```

которое по сути не что иное как

```
tree->prev = tmp;
```

т.е. неинициализированный указатель `tree`, указывающий в фиг куда, и это фиг куда разыменовывается и туда - уже в фиг-фиг куда :) - пишется значение `tmp`...

Так что ваш `tree` должен быть чем-то *реальным*, указывать на реально выделенную память. Чем именно - зависит от вашей задачи, тут вам виднее...

Comment: tree у меня был инициализирован через malloc.  В итоге реализовал через более простую функцию, которая работала бы не с указателями, а возвращала указатель на вновь вставленный элемент. С моей точки зрения алгоритм не поменялся, но работать начало ```struct TreeStruct* pushToStart(struct TreeStruct *pointer)
{
 struct TreeStruct *tmp, *p;
 
 tmp = (struct TreeStruct*)malloc(sizeof(struct TreeStruct*));
 
 tmp->data = 0;
 tmp->next = pointer;
 tmp->prev = NULL;
 
 pointer->prev = tmp;
 
 return(tmp);
}```